# How to disable TFA (Two factor authentication)

Tags: joomla, google-authenticator

I enabled TFA in Joomla 3.2 and it worked fine, but my smartphone is unaccessible.

Then I cannot go in backend and I tried to disable the plugin plg_twofactorauth_totp in database but it stay enabled.

Disabling by rename the folder hide Secret Key input, but I wasn't able to login.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your MySQL database for joomla, go to the **users** table. Clear the value of **otpKey**. you should be able to login without a key now.

Answer (score -1):

https://gist.github.com/medigeek/28a047be0d0d527a95769130a6faf559

This code will disable two-factor auth plugins and clear keys for Joomla! Super Users.

This script disables Joomla!'s two factor authentication plugin and clears the otpKey and otep values for Super Users. It allows you to login when you aren't able to use Google authenticator for any reason.

**Usage:**

Place it in the Joomla! 3.x root dir (where configuration.php and index.php are) and run it. Then login and leave the security key field empty.

**Warning: Use with caution. *Backup* before use!**

Snapshot of the code

```
<?php
/* This script disables Joomla!'s two factor authentication
 * plugin and clears the otpKey and otep values for Super 
 * Users. It allows you to login when you aren't able to
 * use Google authenticator for any reason.

 * Usage:
 * Place it in the Joomla! 3.x root dir (where configuration.php 
 * and index.php are) and run it. Then login and leave the 
 * security key field empty.

 * Warning: Use with caution. Backup before use.
*/
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Load system defines
if (file_exists(JPATH_BASE . '/defines.php')) { require_once JPATH_BASE . '/defines.php'; }
if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) { require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php'; }
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php'; // Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php'; // Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
class Reset2FA extends JApplicationCli
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->out('Initialising');
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
        //get users by group: (array of integers)
        $sadminids = JAccess::getUsersByGroup(8); // 8 = Super Users
        $strsadminids = implode(',', $sadminids);
        $this->out(sprintf('Super User IDs: %s', $strsadminids));
        $this->out('Disabling twofactorauth plugin (totp and yubikey)');
        // Fields to update.
        $fields = array(sprintf('%s = 0', $db->quoteName('enabled')));
        // Conditions for which records should be updated.
        // plg_twofactorauth_totp
        // plg_twofactorauth_yubikey
        $conditions = array(sprintf('%s LIKE %s', $db->quoteName('name'), $db->quote('plg_twofactorauth_%')));
        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->execute();

        $this->out('Disabling/clearing otpKey and otep for all Super Users');
        // UPDATE 2
        $fields2 = array(
            $db->quoteName('otpKey') . " = ''",
            $db->quoteName('otep') . " = ''",
            );
        // Conditions for which records should be updated.
        // otpKey
        // otep
        $conditions2 = array(
            $db->quoteName('otpKey') . " != ''",
            $db->quoteName('otep') . " != ''",
            sprintf('%s IN (%s)', $db->quoteName('id'), $strsadminids)
        );
        $query2->update($db->quoteName('#__users'))->set($fields2)->where($conditions2);
        $db->setQuery($query2);
        $result2 = $db->execute();
        $this->out('Done');
    }
}
JApplicationCli::getInstance('Reset2FA')->execute();
?>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's required to post the whole code to gist github (?)

Comment: There we go, I think it's better now. Thanks!